# How to fine tune an FCN-32s for interactive object segmentation

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, caffe, image-segmentation, conv-neural-network

I'm trying to implement the proposed model in a CVPR paper ([Deep Interactive Object Selection](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1603.04042.pdf)) in which the data set contains 5 channels for each input sample:

1.Red

2.Blue

3.Green

4.Euclidean distance map associated to positive clicks

5.Euclidean distance map associated to negative clicks (as follows):

[image]

[image]

[image]

To do so, I should fine tune the FCN-32s network using "object binary masks" as labels:

[image]

As you see, in the first conv layer I have 2 extra channels, so I did net surgery to use pretrained parameters for the first 3 channels and Xavier initialization for 2 extras.

For the rest of the FCN architecture, I have these questions:

1. Should I freeze all the layers before "fc6" (except the first conv layer)? If yes, how the extra channels of the first conv will be learned? Are the gradients strong enough to reach the first conv layer during training process?
2. What should be the kernel size of the "fc6"? should I keep 7? I saw in "Caffe net_surgery" notebook that it depends on the output size of the last layer ("pool5").
3. The main problem is the number of outputs of the "score_fr" and "upscore" layers, since I'm not doing class segmentation (to use 21 for 20 classes and the background), how should I change it? What about 2? (one for object and the other for the non-object (background) area)?
4. Should I change "crop" layer "offset" to 32 to have center crops?
5. In case of changing each of these layers, what is the best initialization strategy for them? "bilinear" for "upscore" and "Xavier" for the rest?
6. Should I convert my binary label matrix values into zero-centered ( {-0.5,0.5} ) status, or it is OK to use them with the values in {0,1} ?

Any useful idea will be appreciated.

PS:
I'm using Euclidean loss, while I'm using "1" as the number of outputs for "score_fr" and "upscore" layers. If I use 2 for that, I guess it should be softmax.

Answer (score 1):

I can answer some of your questions.

1. The gradients will reach the first layer so it should be possible to learn the weights even if you freeze the other layers.
2. Change the `num_output` to 2 and finetune. You should get a good output.
3. I think you'll need to experiment with each of the options and see how the accuracy is.
4. You can use the values 0,1.

Comment: Thanks for your replay, at the moment, I'm using Euclidean loss, so I thought maybe I should have just one output for my score layer (the network prediction that is the first input of my loss layer), after some training iterations, I checked the result and it seems that the network is going to learn what I expected. But the loss function is somewhat overwhelming. As I understood, it is the normalized Euclidean distance over all the samples of the mini batch. Since I couldn't use a batch size more than 8, it seems natural to have heavy loss instability.

Comment: You should use softmax loss. It is meant to be used for classification problems but isn't segmentation really pixel-wise classification. ;)

Comment: In this case, should I use two labels, one for object and the other that is reversed of the first one for background?

Comment: No need. Softmax loss should do that automatically for you. Look at FCN training net. They use a softmax loss layer.

Comment: Yes, I have seen that before, but I thought maybe I need another loss, many thanks.